# ASP.NET - Ajax success params from controller

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

I have an table of items with a delete link for every line.

the link looks like:

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Items", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", Confirm = "Delete the item?", OnFailure = "errorHandler.onFailure(xhr, status, error)", UpdateTargetId = "item_" + item.Id })
```

The called onFailure-Methode looks like this:

```
var errorHandler = {
     onFailure: function (xhr, status, error) {
          console.log("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: " + xhr);
          alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
};
```

the controller-delete-methode  looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id) {
      try {
            var item = _itemService.GetById(id);
            _itemService.Delete(item);
            return new EmptyResult();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            return Content(message);
      }
```

This all works fine as long as I do it on local debugger. When publishing to iis the alert does not only show the message, but a kind of error page, created by iis.

UPDATE => Result from IIS:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>500 - Interner Serverfehler.</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--

       body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
       fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
       h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
       h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
       h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
       #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
       background-color:#555555;}
       #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}

       .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}

       -->

     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="header"><h1>Serverfehler</h1></div>
        <div id="content">
        <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
        <h2>500 - Interner Serverfehler.</h2>
        <h3>Problem bei der gesuchten Ressource. Sie kann nicht angezeigt werden.</h3>
        </fieldset></div>
        </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Why is this so? Can I solve this? Am I on the right track or is there a better way to implement deleting of items?

Comment: what is that error ? Can you post that as part of the question >?

Comment: I added the response from iis!

Comment: 500 internal server error means some error in your code. Put a try catch and write the error details (Stacktrace,inner excpetions to a log) and inspect that.

Comment: Think you didn't understand my querstion. If you look at the controller code, you see that I explicitly set status code to 500, because ajax-method of javascript needs it.